# How Can I create a Message Box like Groove Music in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, messagebox

I need to Show information in a Message Box like this:

[image: messagebox]

How can i create a similar Message box?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is create a simple message box with a title, text content and customizable buttons (commands), then use the [MessageDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) class.

```
private void showDialog()
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("You have unsaved changes. Continue?", "Warning");
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK", handler));
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel", handler));
    dialog.ShowAsync();
}

private void handler(IUICommand command)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"The user clicked {command.Label}");
}
```

[image: MessageDialog screenshot]

If you need something more custom, then you'll need to subclass the [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) class. Right click your project in Solution Explorer > Add > New Item, and choose Content Dialog from the list. You can use the XAML editor to customize the appearance of the dialog, choose the buttons to display, etc.

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="App9.MyDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App9"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    PrimaryButtonText="OK"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancel">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Run>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet iaculis sapien, in lacinia sem auctor quis.
                Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam finibus eu sapien quis
                ultricies. In tristique nec magna quis fermentum. Pellentesque elit urna, tincidunt sit amet suscipit non, lacinia
                vitae orci. Etiam vel tortor neque.
            </Run>
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run>
                Integer dictum tortor at quam feugiat, vel eleifend neque accumsan. Maecenas
                pellentesque, augue sed vulputate placerat, erat urna aliquam erat, a posuere mi massa vitae velit. Donec gravida
                dui quis tortor semper, vel efficitur leo ultricies. Sed tincidunt ultrices dui, vitae congue purus venenatis a.
                Ut aliquam neque leo, a vehicula nisl fermentum elementum. In euismod, erat ac congue fermentum, dui nunc ultrices
                tellus, vitae fringilla risus felis at tortor.
            </Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

You can display the dialog like this:

```
private async Task displayDialogAsync()
{
    var dialog = new MyDialog();  // Whatever you named your ContentDialog subclass
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

    if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
    {
        // User clicked OK
    }
    else if (result == ContentDialogResult.Secondary)
    {
        // User clicked Cancel
    }
}
```

[image: ContentDialog screenshot]

Comment: I'm trying to make my message box look similar to this

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to subclass the `ContentDialog` to use it:

```
ContentDialog CD_Popup = new ContentDialog();

CD_Popup.Title = "Title";
CD_Popup.Content = "Content";
CD_Popup.PrimaryButtonText = "Primary button text";
CD_Popup.PrimaryButtonClick += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Primary button method
};
CD_Popup.SecondaryButtonText = "Secondary button text";
CD_Popup.SecondaryButtonClick += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Secondary button method
};

await CD_Popup.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: You should subclass it if you have a custom content (i.e. something other than a string), which you can design in the XAML editor, or if it requires custom code (like validating a form, for example). For simple string-content dialogs, MessageDialog suffices.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I know, but the ContentDialog has different placement (on mobile is on top, not centered) and on PC it looks the same as on mobile - not using the old W8 design.